# Dismiss throw error message in google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, throw

I'm using google scripts for the first time and have a question regarding throw messages.
After showing a error message in the google sheets, we get a red dialogue box showing that message. It stays there till the dismissed button is not pressed. And keeps on gathering on the screen.

Is there a way to auto dismiss these thrown messages?
[The following image shows the gathered error messages which stays there till the dismissed button is not pressed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaUCF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use try/catch

```
function test() {
  try {
    SpreadsheetApp.openById('1234567890')
  }
  catch (e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(e)
  }
}
```

or

```
function test() {
  try {
    SpreadsheetApp.openById('1234567890')
  }
  catch (e) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The toast are working, is there a way to change its color to red?

Comment: No, AFAIK there is no possibility according to the documentation https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toastmsg. But you can evnetually post a new topic on StackOverflow